# DynamoDB: is there an optimal way to model data that is shared and accessed by all users frequently?

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, partitioning

Let's say I have users in a table, with the user id being the primary key. Most information is specific to the user. I want to be able to communicate with my users so I want the ability to make announcements to them. These announcements are shared across all the users. I can store user-specific information about announcements in their own attributes in a user row (like read and unread announcements, or latest announcement viewed).

The problem (if it's not clear already) is that there is only one set of announcements but they will be queried by every user frequently, leading to an anti-pattern of DynamoDB and potential throttling.

My initial thoughts are to make k copies of announcements and label the keys announcement_copy_1, announcement_copy_2 ... announcement_copy_k, and then on the query to check for new announcements, I would randomly assign an integer 1-k to query the announcements. Each announcement copy would be the partition key and I would have sort keys with the date of the specific announcement, and attributes with the text and type of announcement.

I'm not confident if this is the best approach to this problem, or if I'm missing something. Also I am looking at going serverless with AWS Lambdas if that affects anything.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or advice!

Comment: Why don't you create a separate `announcements` table?

Comment: @mdem7 I'm scared that just creating an announcements table isn't enough since there is only one set of announcements and all users will query that one set, which will lead to it being a hot partition. Announcements wouldn't be evenly distributed since users would try and obtain the most recent announcements most likely. Not sure if I'm being overly paranoid or if this is something I should account for in DyanmoDB.

Comment: Hot partitions only matter when you have more than one partition in your table—you probably won’t have more than one if you have a table dedicated just for announcements. Furthermore, thanks to Adaptive Capacity, hot partitions are basically a thing of the past. See https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-is-now-instant/